# Self hosting apache permissions trouble

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I am trying to self host a PHP script called sngine. (facebook clone)

When trying to install it I get an error:

> config.php - Required includes folder to be writable for the installation

when I run `ls -l` I get this: `drwxrwxrwx 5 mbeck mbeck   4096 Aug 25 23:00 includes`

I don't know why it is saying that it's not writable.

The script is in `var/www/{domain name}/`
I am on Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) and PHP version: 7.4.22

**EDIT:**
I found someone saying to run `chown www-data:www-data <directory>` So I did, and permissions now return `drwxrwxrwx 5 www-data www-data   4096 Aug 25 23:00 includes` and the error is still there.

Comment: have you given the permission to folder?

Comment: I think so. like I posted in the question permissions are drwxrwxrwx. is that what it should be?

Comment: Who's the owner of the entire directory, not just the `includes`? (i.e. whos the owner of `config.php`?)

Comment: Yes, that seems like it was the issue. run sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/example.com/mydomain/includes/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it!

I had to run sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/example.com/mydomain/includes/

Now it works!

Comment: don't leave user www-data with write permissions on your server files, if Apache is compromised by someone they will be able to destroy ALL files on your server that Apache has write access to